# React class component cannot be used as a JSX component if returns type of ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple class component:

```
import { Component, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

interface State {
  hasError: boolean;
}

class Friends extends Component<Props, State> {
  public render(): ReactNode {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default Friends;
```

And I use this component like this:

```
<Friends>
  <p>i like my friends</p>
</Friends>
```

Stack Snippet:

```js
const { Component, ReactNode } = React;
/*
interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

interface State {
  hasError: boolean;
}
*/
class Friends extends Component/*<Props, State>*/ {
  /*public*/ render()/*: ReactNode*/ {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Friends>
    <p>i like my friends</p>
  </Friends>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVoqhgHIQAmScAvnAGZRFwDkU1M3ANwAoUJFhV0MACIB5ALLtOIOACI+UgLT0iqkaIpIobdEwAKnMAGdcwuHDQALYABt6fEgC5JtBkhHMwgYwRiZoTADKMCghtvaOKFYAolCcUN4ARhAQLqgkAUFoLok2AGJQwOT0NkgAHiEk1QREkGQUADwWENbYUTFIAHxxcGAArhkuwGhwHoxQABQAlN7IUnSMw-Z8MKNQJHAwzlYAdGCWJ06u7uQi9oGBwqsYcvLHs0bzdnDt5ZWNVgMvvZ2mABsA4JMANZMEAATyUf2q7QA9KCvijflUAZgvjo0KMQOQYMcAOZIGBJXKEigAIVhAEl6PN1NkYKpFsJFoIgA)

It throws typescript error:

> 'Friends' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type
> 'Friends' is not a valid JSX element. The types returned by 'render()'
> are incompatible between these types.  Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("somepath/node_modules/@types/react-router/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Why am I getting this error? I simplified this example to this simple class but my goal was to implement ErrorBoundary component from react-error-boundary but it didn't work either.

TsConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't give that error for that code ([link](https://tsplay.dev/Nnaekw)), nor does React when it runs (I've added a runnable Stack Snippet to your question demonstrating the latter; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)). Please update the question to demonstrate the error, for instance if there's some specific `tsconfig.json` setting required, or different code, or...

Comment: Separately, though: There's no need to define a return type on your `render` implementation. It's already defined by `Component`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right actually, it breaks only in my codebase. I updated the question with my tsconfig.json. And I've got some eslint rule that requires me to specify return type.

Comment: Again, please try to replicate the error in the TypeScript playground. You can use the TSConfig button to set config options to match yours.